# Android How to insert control in fragment in android

Tags: android

How to insert control like buttonOnClickListener   ImageOnClickListener in Fragment in android

Comment: Show what have you tried for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can place it in the xml for the fragment as any other view

I guess you might be having trouble with context, use 'getActivity()' to get tht context of the Activity or you can also use 'ParentActivity.class'.

You night be used to used to using 'this' as context when you are using buttons in 'Activity' but 'this' can't be used when you want to use button in fragment as 'this' would refer to the 'Fragment' and not to the 'Activity'

The following code can be used in 'onCreate()' of 'Fragment'

```
 Button btn = new Button(getActivity());
     btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Please feel free to ask any further doubts and do let me know whether this solves your problem

Comment: @user2006249 I have pasted the code to create a button with onClick listener in fragment's ' onCreate() '

Comment: Please can you send me your mail address i will send it my code?

Comment: praveen.3490@gmail.com . you can post your code in stack overflow itself. Copy your code edit your question , press enter twice to give a new line give 4 spaces and paste it